# What is ! and : used for in REXX

Tags: rexx

What does the ! and : do in REXX. 
For instance in this piece of code

```
!all:!!=!;!=space(!);upper !;call !fid;!nt=right(!var('OS'),2)=='NT';!cls=word('CLS VMFCLEAR CLRSCREEN',1+!cms+!tso*2);if arg(1)\==1 then return 0;if wordpos(!,'? ?SAMPLES ?AUTHOR ?FLOW')==0 then return 0;!call=']$H';call '$H' !fn !;!call=;return 1
!cal:if symbol('!CALL')\=="VAR" then !call=;return !call
!env:!env='ENVIRONMENT';if !sys=='MSDOS'|!brexx|!r4|!roo then !env='SYSTEM';if !os2 then !env='OS2'!env;!ebcdic=1=='f0'x;return
!fid:parse upper source !sys !fun !fid . 1 . . !fn !ft !fm .;call !sys;if !dos then do;_=lastpos('\',!fn);!fm=left(!fn,_);!fn=substr(!fn,_+1);parse var !fn !fn '.' !ft;end;return word(0 !fn !ft !fm,1+('0'arg(1)))
!rex:parse upper version !ver !vernum !verdate .;!brexx='BY'==!vernum;!kexx='KEXX'==!ver;!pcrexx='REXX/PERSONAL'==!ver|'REXX/PC'==!ver;!r4='REXX-R4'==!ver;!regina='REXX-REGINA'==left(!ver,11);!roo='REXX-ROO'==!ver;call !env;return
!sys:!cms=!sys=='CMS';!os2=!sys=='OS2';!tso=!sys=='TSO'|!sys=='MVS';!vse=!sys=='VSE';!dos=pos('DOS',!sys)\==0|pos('WIN',!sys)\==0|!sys=='CMD';call !rex;return
!var:call !fid;if !kexx then return space(dosenv(arg(1)));return space(value(arg(1),,!env))
```

What is the `!all:!!=!` doing?
I actually have a lot of questions looking at this piece of code but I figured we would start there and see if that sheds some light on the rest.

The original code sample is located here http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Terminal_control/Coloured_text#REXX

Comment: The '!' character is just another character you can use in 'variable names. So, instead of 'i' in for loops you could use '!'. [Search for symbols](http://www.oorexx.org/docs/rexxref/x436.htm). The ':' is used at the end of a 'name' it indicate it is a 'label'. see: [12. Subroutines and functions](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/ian.collier/Docs/rexx_info/whole.html#L). Trying to make sense of the 'optimized code that ia shown will be 'interesting' but is possible.

Comment: @RyanVincent do you want to put that as an answer and I'll upvote?  Else, I'll put it as an answer and steal your fake internet points.  Mwahahaha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answered in the comments by [Ryan Vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3184785/ryan-vincent):

The `!` character is just another character you can use in 'variable names. So, instead of `i` in for loops you could use `!`. See the [documentation](http://www.oorexx.org/docs/rexxref/x436.htm) and search for symbols.

The `:` is used at the end of a 'name' it indicate it is a 'label'. see: 12. [Subroutines and functions](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/ian.collier/Docs/rexx_info/whole.html#L). Trying to make sense of the 'optimized code that is shown will be 'interesting' but is possible. –  Ryan Vincent Apr 18 at 19:55